# Netflix eureka Microservice

Tags: java

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Apr 19 14:13:07 IST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
status 401 reading UserFeignClient#getUserByUsername(String)
feign.FeignException: status 401 reading UserFeignClient#getUserByUsername(String)
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:78)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:93)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:149)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:78)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy214.getUserByUsername(Unknown Source)

service2 to tries to read service1 - getting the above error

Answer (score 0):

Service1  was down , so Implemented Hystrix with fallback method

@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod= "fallbackUser",
threadPoolKey="itemByUserThreadPool",threadPoolProperties= {@HystrixProperty(name="coreSize",value="30"),
@HystrixProperty(name="maxQueueSize",value="10")    })
    public User getUserByUsername(String username) {

```
    return userFeignClient.getUserByUsername(username);
}
```

//fallback method

```
private User fallbackUser(String username)
{
    User user =new User();
    user.setId(111L);
    user.setFirstName("TestName");      
    return user;
}
```